# Facing issue in getting code coverage for android app using gradle 7.5 when appium test are executed

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, code-coverage, jacoco

I have an android project which was recently updated from gradle 6.7 to gradle 7.5, and it broke the code coverage workflow.

Scenario:
I have an android project named `Android-Example-Project` and it uses gradle 7.5, jacoco 0.8.11, java 11.
I have another project which has appium based UI tests and uses maven.

I had followed some examples found on stackoverflow to setup the code coverage for appium tests run separately using maven, and it worked when we were using gradle 6.7, now it throws me following error:

```
[ant:jacocoReport] Execution data for class <CLASS_NAME> does not match.
```

and the final report has 0% coverage.

Here are the steps I followed:

I made changes in Android project for code coverage instrumentation:

step 1. Added a class `CodeCoverageInstrumentation.java`

```
package com.example.instrumentation;

import android.util.Log;
import android.app.Instrumentation;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager;

public class CodeCoverageInstrumentation extends Instrumentation {
    private Intent intent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle arguments) {
        Log.d("Code Coverage Instrumentation", "Code Coverage Instrumentation created.");
        intent = getTargetContext().getPackageManager()
                .getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.debug")
                .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        start(); 
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        Log.d("Code Coverage Instrumentation", "Code Coverage Instrumentation started.");
        startActivitySync(intent);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getTargetContext()).registerReceiver(
                new EndEmmaBroadcast(), new IntentFilter("com.example.debug.END_EMMA"));
    }
}
```

step 2. Added another class `EndEmmaBroadcast.java`

```
package com.example.instrumentation;

import java.io.File;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Process;
import android.util.Log;

@SuppressLint("SdCardPath")
public class EndEmmaBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("AppiumEmma", "EndEmmaBroadcast broadcast received!");
        try {
            Class.forName("com.vladium.emma.rt.RT")
                    .getMethod("dumpCoverageData", File.class, boolean.class, boolean.class)
                    .invoke(null, new File("/data/data/com.example.debug/coverage.ec"), false, false);
            Log.d("AppiumEmma", "Coverage data dumped!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("AppiumEmma", Log.getStackTraceString(e));
        }
    }
}
```

step 3. Changes in `AndroidManifest.xml`

Added these code snippets:

```
<instrumentation
    android:name="com.example.instrumentation.CodeCoverageInstrumentation"
    android:targetPackage="com.example.debug" >
</instrumentation>
```

and

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.instrumentation.EndEmmaBroadcast" android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.debug.END_EMMA" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

step 4. Changes in root level `build.gradle`:
Added below code snippet:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'org.jacoco:org.jacoco.report:0.8.11'
        force 'org.jacoco:org.jacoco.core:0.8.11'
        force 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:3.0.19'
    }
}
```

step 5. Changes in app level `build.gradle`:
Added below code snippet after buildscript block:

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.8.11"
}
```

Also, added below code snippet

```
task("jacoco\${variant.name.capitalize()}TestReport", type: JacocoReport) {
    description 'Generate Jacoco coverage reports after running tests.'
    group 'Reporting'
    def fileFilter = [
        '**/R.class',
        '**/R\$*.class',
        '**/*\$ViewInjector*.*',
        '**/*\$ViewBinder*.*',
        '**/BuildConfig.*',
        '**/Manifest*.*'
    ]
    classDirectories.from(fileTree(
                dir: "\${buildDir}/intermediates/javac/\${variant.name}/classes/com/",
                excludes: fileFilter
            ) + fileTree(
                dir: "\${buildDir}/tmp/kotlin-classes/\${variant.name}/com/",
                excludes: fileFilter
            )
        )
        sourceDirectories.from(fileTree(
                dir: "\${project.projectDir}/src/com/example/"
            )
        )
        executionData.from(fileTree(dir: "\$buildDir", includes: [
            "codecoverage/data/*.ec"
        ])
        )
        onlyIf = {
            true
        }

        reports {
            xml.enabled true
            csv.enabled false
            html.enabled true
        }
    }
```

After these changes in android project I have made some changes in Appium automation project to invoke instrumentation before test run and end it in teardown:

step 1. Added desired capability for instrumentation while initiating test:

```
cap.setCapability("androidCoverage", "com.example.debug/com.example.instrumentation.CodeCoverageInstrumentation");
```

step 2. Made changes to end coverage and generate `.ec` file in teardown:

```
@AfterMethod(groups = "tearDown", alwaysRun = true)
public void teardown(ITestResult result, @Optional String udId) {
    String testname = result.getMethod().getMethodName();
    Log.info("Dumping coverage data");
    Map<String, Object> args = new HashMap<>();
        
    // Execute shell to broadcast end coverage
    args.put("command", "am broadcast -a com.example.debug.END_EMMA com.example.debug");
    getAndroidDriver().executeScript("mobile: shell", args);
    args.clear();
        
    // Rename coverage.ec to <test_method_name>.ec
    args.put("command", "run-as com.example.debug mv /data/data/com.example.debug/coverage.ec /data/data/com.example.debug/coverage_"+testname+".ec");
    getAndroidDriver().executeScript("mobile: shell", args);
 
    // Pull .ec file from mobile device to computer
    pullData(udId, "/data/data/com.example.debug/coverage_"+testname+".ec", testname);

    // Quit driver
    Log.info("Shutting down driver");
    getAndroidDriver().quit();
}

public static void pullData(String udId, String sourcePath, String testname){
    try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"bash","-c","adb -s "+udId+" exec-out run-as com.example.debug cat "+sourcePath+" > coverage_"+testname+".ec"});
    } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.info("Coverage file pull failed.");
    }
}
```

After these changes I execute the tests with this command:

```
mvn clean test -DsuiteXmlFile=<XML_FILE>
```

and I get multiple ec files in the end of testsuite run. then I collect these ec files in build folder under `codecoverage/data/` folder and execute jacoco test report gradle task:

```
./gradlew jacoco<variant>TestReport
```

When we had gradle 6.7, It used to generate an xml and html file with proper code coverage but now it just gives the error and generates 0% coverage report.

I have made sure that the same java version is used throughout the execution, but still no luck.

Please help me find out what can be done here.